# PHP: E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR: Instantiation of 'Closure' is not allowed?

Tags: php, closures

Hello unfortunatly I cannot find much information on this error on Google and I wonder what the problem is. I have an array containing a lot of information, including some closures (code example is shortened):

```
$create_info = array (
'foo' => 'bar',
'create_connection_object' => function ($my_key,$foreign_key) {
     return new ApConnection(intval($my_key), intval($foreign_key));
},
'hello' => 'world'
);
```

Then I have a method using this array depending on the context:

```
$create_connection_object = $create_info['create_connection_object'];
$con = new $create_connection_object(intval($request->first_id),intval($request->second_id));
```

When executing this code I get the following error:

```
"E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR: Instantiation of 'Closure' is not allowed"
```

In another context I got something working which looks quite similar (closure from array) and instantiated dynamically. Does anybody know a reason why this may fail?

Comment: It seems your callback already creates a `new` object, namely an ApConnection. So you are trying to `new`en it again, even though your $create_con_ callback already did.

Comment: Oh man... O:-P Thanks, sometimes there are just stupid simple mistakes which I do not SEE at 4 o'clock in the morning. Be free to make an answer of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 o'clock projects are usually the most productive. And this is actually a pretty neat reference question on this specific error message.

Your `$create_connection_object()` closure is misunderstood by PHP.

```
 = new $create_connection_object(..)
```

Would indeed look like `= new Closure()` to the interpreter, because `$create_con_` is already an anonymous function. (It would only work if your variable contained a literal classname string).

The `new` was redundant, because the callback itself already returns a `new ApConnection`. So just calling it with `$con =`<s>`new`</s>`$create_con_()` was sufficient to return the object your closure instantiates beforehand.